# Write a self join query?

Tags: sql, join

I have the following table with values

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpEmployee(ID int, EmpName varchar(50), EmpBossID int)

insert into #tmpEmployee values ( 1, 'Abhijit', 2);
insert into #tmpEmployee values ( 2, 'Haris', 3);
insert into #tmpEmployee values ( 3, 'Sanal', 0);
```

Now I want the result become following

```
ID  EmpName BossName
1   Abhijit Haris
2   Haris   Sanal
```

so I have written the following query.

```
select E1.ID,E1.EmpName, E.EmpName as BossName from #tmpEmployee E inner join #tmpEmployee E1 on E1.EmpBossID=E.ID.
```

But the problem is the 3rd employee (Sanal) has no boss.
So I want this exact result:

```
ID  EmpName BossName
1   Abhijit Haris
2   Haris   Sanal
3   Sanal   Null
```

What should I do?

Comment: Replace the `inner join` with [`left outer join`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-join).

Comment: select E1.ID,E1.EmpName, E.EmpName as BossName from #tmpEmployee E Left Outer join #tmpEmployee E1 on E1.EmpBossID=E.ID tried but result become  ID EmpName BossName
NULL NULL Abhijit
1 Abhijit Haris
2 Haris Sanal

Comment: Just switch it to a RIGHT join.

Comment: @Haris - I didn't look close enough at the expected results and your current statement but the crux is that you should look up the difference between an `inner` and an `outer` join.

Comment: ok Lieven Keersmaekers thanks for your advice

Comment: possible duplicate of [self join query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344098/self-join-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Right Join

```
 select E1.ID,E1.EmpName, E.EmpName as BossName from #tmpEmployee E right join #tmpEmployee E1 on E1.EmpBossID=E.ID

ID  EmpName BossName
1   Abhijit Haris
2   Haris   Sanal
3   Sanal   NULL
```

I think its ok for u

Answer (score 1):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` and reverse the order of your tables:

```
select
  E.ID,
  E.EmpName,
  B.EmpName as BossName
from tmpEmployee E
left join tmpEmployee B on E.EmpBossID = B.ID
```

See a [**live demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6cb9e/8) of this query on SQLFiddle

Putting the "employee" part of the join *first* means that all employees are listed.

Using a *left* join means that employees without a boss (eg the CEO) will still be listed, but will have a `null` for the `BossName` column.

If you truly want only employee listed if they have a boss, change the query to simply `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` (note that the default join type is `INNER`)

p.s. formatting your query doesn't hurt either:

Comment: Thanks for u r advice . But answer become not correct it getting result as   ID EmpName BossName
1 Abhijit NULL
2 Haris Abhijit
3 Sanal Haris

Comment: Oops! Got the join around the wrong way. I've updated the query and sqlfiddle link. Renaming the table aliases made it clearer too. It works correctly now

Answer (score 0):

try out this...

Use Left Join..

```
select E.ID,E.EmpName, E1.EmpName as BossName from #tmpEmployee E left outer join #tmpEmployee E1 on E1.EmpBossID=E.ID

ID  EmpName BossName
1   Abhijit Haris
2   Haris   Sanal
3   Sanal   NULL
```

Comment: No that not correct. I am getting answer become ID EmpName BossName
NULL NULL Abhijit
1 Abhijit Haris
2 Haris Sanal

Comment: No that also getting wrong answer. Atleast u make sure that posting cmnt are correct